# The sentence structure analysis

Tags: sentence-construction

> "Wretched creatures that we are! **what resource for us amidst the
>   innumerable ills of life**, did not religion suggest some methods of
>   atonement, and appease those terrors, with which we are incessantly
>   agitated and tormented?"

*From Dialogues Concerning Natural Religion by David Hume*

About the second sentence structure, I have some questions.

First, why is the first letter of what (the starting word of the second sentence) not capital? As far as I know, exclamation mark serves the same syntactic function as period, so it should be **"What"** rather than "what", I guess.

Second, more confusing one, what is the status or meaning or function of the phrase "what resource for us amidst the innumerable ills of life," in the sentence? I think "religion" should be the subject, and "did not suggest"(inversion form) the verb phrase. I do not understand what the phrase is doing exactly. Please enlighten me with the pre-inverted sentence.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

18th-century punctuation tended to be rhetorical rather than syntactical, and the exclamation point marks only Hume's emphasis on the preceding noun phrase, not a full stop. This is still common in informal writing.

> I got an A! on my history test.

The interrogative ellipts its verb:  *what resource **would there be** for us...*. Again, you will still encounter this today:

> What use asking if you know he's going to say 'no'?

Comment: There's also the archaic phrasing of *did not religion suggest some methods of atonement...*, which I think you probably *wouldn't* encounter today (it would always be ***if religion did not** suggest...*). But it's a brave learner who would try to get to grips with text like this.

Comment: Thank both of you very much for kind replies. Really helpful.